# Working out MSQ Response Collection

Tags: c#, dictionary, radio-button, checkbox

Long story short, I'm working on an exam-taking application as part of my internship. I'm currently on the candidate console module, which is responsible for displaying questions per section and collecting responses. Response collection is based on the type of question that is offered. If the question is multiple choice, the candidate console displays it using a groupbox of (custom) radio buttons. For example -:

[MCQ Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UezAT.png)

If the question is multiple select, the candidate console displays it using a groupbox of (custom) checkboxes. For example -:

[MSQ Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CG8mt.png)

I've been able to successfully implement MCQ response collection with some help from IRC. However, following the same logic, I've hit a stumbling block in the implementation of MSQ response collection.

```
//This is in the QuestionDisplay class.
//MCQ
public void AddOption_mcq(string optionText, bool arg, int QNo, int option)
{
     CustomRadio rb = new CustomRadio();
     rb.Text = optionText;
     rb.Location = new Point(3, 40 + grbOptions.Controls.Count * 30);
     rb.AutoSize = true;
     rb.Checked = arg;
     rb.QuestionNumber = QNo;
     rb.optionId = option;
     rb.CheckedChanged += delegate(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
     {
           temp = sender as CustomRadio;
           if (!ResponseMCQ.ContainsKey(QNo)) //First time question is marked, ResponseMCQ is a <int,ButtonBase> dict.
           {
                ResponseMCQ.Add(QNo, temp);
           }
           else
                ResponseMCQ[QNo] = temp; //All other times
     };
     grbOptions.Controls.Add(rb); //grbOptions is a groupbox control.
}

//MSQ
public void AddOption_msq(string optionText, bool arg, int QNo, int option)
{
     CustomChecks cb = new CustomChecks();
     cb.Text = optionText;
     cb.Location = new Point(3, 40 + grbOptions.Controls.Count * 30);
     cb.AutoSize = true;
     cb.Checked = arg;
     cb.QuestionNumber = QNo;
     cb.optionId = option;
     cb.CheckedChanged += delegate(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
     {
          temp = sender as CustomChecks;
          if(MSQs.Any())
              foreach (CustomChecks C in MSQs) //Clear elements from List if on a different question
              {
                   if (C.QuestionNumber != ((CustomChecks)temp).QuestionNumber)
                   {
                       IsDifferent = true;
                       break;
                   }
              }
          if (IsDifferent == true)
          {
               MSQs.Clear();
               IsDifferent = false;
          }
          if(!MSQs.Any(x => x.Text.Equals(optionText))) //Check if the checkbox already exists in the List
               MSQs.Add(temp);
          if (!ResponseMSQ.ContainsKey(QNo)) //First time the question is marked
          {
               ResponseMSQ.Add(QNo, MSQs);
          }
          else
               ResponseMSQ[QNo] = MSQs; //All other times
    };
    grbOptions.Controls.Add(cb);
    if (MSQs.Any())
    {
          foreach (CustomChecks C in MSQs)
          {
               foreach (CustomChecks D in grbOptions.Controls)
               {
                    if (D.Text.Equals(C.Text))
                    {
                        D.Checked = C.Checked;
                    }
               }
          }
    }
}

//In the main project, this is how I collect MCQ responses -:
temp = questionDisplay1.GetResponse; //questionDisplay1 is a QuestionDisplay object and GetResponse is a ButtonBase object, used to temporarily store the clicked radio button(CustomRadio object).
//MCQResponse is a Dictionary<int, ButtonBase> which stores <QuestionNumber, CustomRadio>.
if (QuesTypes[i].Equals("MCQ"))
{
         if (questionDisplay1.MCQResponse.TryGetValue(i, out temp) && questionDisplay1.MCQResponse[i].Text.Equals(s))
         {
               questionDisplay1.AddOption_mcq(s, true, i, optionId);
         }
         else
               questionDisplay1.AddOption_mcq(s, false, i, optionId);
}
```

`MCQResponse` and `MSQResponse` are of type `Dictionary<int, ButtonBase>` and `Dictionary<int, List<ButtonBase>>` respectively. They store data according to a QuestionNumber:Object mapping, where Object may be `CustomRadio` or `CustomChecks`.

For MCQs, I use a temporary ButtonBase object, `temp`, to store the CustomRadio object when it is clicked (CheckedChanged event). For the first time the question is marked, the dictionary is checked. If not present, the entry is added. For all other times, the entry is simply edited.

Now for MSQs, I'm trying to follow a similar logic but am screwing up somewhere. I use a temporary List object, `MSQs`, to store multiple CustomChecks responses. In the first if case, I clear the List if I am on a different question from the one in which I clicked a checkbox. Next, I check if the checkbox is not already present in the List. If not present, I add it. Lastly, I use a similar logic as in MCQ response collection.

The `foreach` loop at the end was added for the sake of displaying the CustomChecks elements properly. I ought to be using MSQResponse for that purpose, but I'm not able to figure out how. Here are the main problems I'm facing -:

- MSQ responses are persistently displayed only for one question. If I select checkboxes in another question, the previous ones are not displayed. I have to build code in the main project similar to how I've done for MCQs, and am not able to figure it out for that purpose.
- The use of `MSQResponse`. I'm not using it properly for sure. There has to be a more efficient way to collect MSQ responses using this dictionary.
- The double foreach loop at the end of the MSQ method is quite expensive. I have heard of Zip operations in .NET 4, but I'm using .NET 3.5 on strict instructions by my project in-charge. It is only for the purpose of displaying persistently, but it works only for one question. If I could do away with it altogether, I'd be glad.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

---

### **EDIT**

So, I tried out the approach given by James Holderness. Code is as follows -:

```
public void AddOption_msq(string optionText, bool arg, int QNo, int option)
{
        CustomChecks cb = new CustomChecks();
        cb.Text = optionText;
        cb.Location = new Point(3, 40 + grbOptions.Controls.Count * 30);
        cb.AutoSize = true;
        cb.Checked = arg;
        cb.QuestionNumber = QNo;
        cb.optionId = option;

        cb.CheckedChanged += delegate(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            temp = sender as CustomChecks;
            if (!ResponseMSQ.ContainsKey(QNo))
            {
                // First time, add an empty list
                ResponseMSQ.Add(QNo, new List<ButtonBase>());
            } 
            if (!ResponseMSQ[QNo].Any(x => x.Text.Equals(optionText))) //Check if the checkbox already exists in the List
            {
                ResponseMSQ[QNo].Add(temp);
            }
            if (((CustomChecks)temp).Checked == false) //Removing the checkbox if deselected
            {
                foreach (CustomChecks C in ResponseMSQ[QNo])
                    if (C.Text.Equals(temp.Text))
                    {
                        ResponseMSQ[QNo].Remove(C);
                        break;
                    }

            }
        };
        grbOptions.Controls.Add(cb);
        if (ResponseMSQ.ContainsKey(QNo) && ResponseMSQ[QNo].Any()) //For persistently displaying the proper checked state.
        {
            foreach (CustomChecks C in ResponseMSQ[QNo])
            {
                foreach (CustomChecks D in grbOptions.Controls)
                {
                    if (D.Text.Equals(C.Text))
                    {
                        D.Checked = C.Checked;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

This works quite well. I debugged to check whether -:

1. Responses were being stored: ResponseMSQ was storing them as was needed.
2. Checkboxes were being displayed as required: The state of the checkboxes was being displayed properly due to the double `foreach` at the end.

Now the only concern that remains is about the running time of the double `foreach`, but this solution works. If anyone knows a better way than iterating through two lists at once, they can post it in comments. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My C#/.NET is a bit rusty, but would it not be easier in your MSQ `CheckedChanged` delegate to do something like this:

```
temp = sender as CustomChecks;
if (!ResponseMSQ.ContainsKey(QNo)) 
{                             
    // First time, add an empty list
    ResponseMSQ.Add(QNo, new List<ButtonBase>());
} 
// At this point you're guaranteed there's something in the dictionary
// for your QNo, even if it's just an empty list.                                    
if (!ResponseMSQ[QNo].Any(x => x.Text.Equals(optionText)))
{
    // If the checkbox isn't already in the list, then add it
    ResponseMSQ[QNo].Add(temp); 
}
```

In both the MCQ and MSQ cases you never remove anything from these dictionaries though. Is it never possible for someone to change their response?

Comment: Notice the `ResponseMCQ[QNo] = temp;` line. It helps in changing response. A radio button cannot be deselected. And I'm going to try this approach and post the results.